# How to view which mac addresses are connected to some AP?

Tags: network, windows, wifi, mac-address

I set up an open AP. I know I can view mac addresses of connected users via AP's console (local console). this is not what I need.

I use tool like Netstumbler or inSSIDer on my Win 7 machine to see all wifi users in my surrounding area. However, I cannot see which users are connected to which AP.

How can I detect which users are connected to which AP? what tool should I use?

Comment: I'm not clear on what problem you are trying to solve.  What's wrong with viewing the MAC addresses of connected users, via the AP's console (web administration service)?  Why is this not what you need?

Comment: @D.W. There is no problem with it. The only pain is that I have to sit by the PC which has LAN connection to wifi AP. So I need to see connected users without having to be in that room, let's say from coffee bar on the ground floor.

Comment: You should be able to log into the administrative console on the access point through a wireless connection.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I forgot about it. What about security testing? Can someone see users connected to my AP? Can my competitor see how many users have connected to each of my AP?

Answer (score 3):

For Windows you can use Kismet, might be a bit less easy to play with like netstumbler, but it records all the APs and all the clients, their beacons and so on.
Also you can export its XML files to several other scripts and programs to get better representation then netstumbler and inssider.

In Linux best answer is aircrack suite: run airodump-ng with the right flags on monitor mode enabled card.

Your screen will be divided into two groups, in the top part you'll see all the AP's your card can see, and at the bottom part of the screen you'll see list of clients, where connected clients will have to their left the mac address of the AP they are connected to.

try
airmon-ng start wlan0 && airodump-ng mon0

where wlan0 is your wifi card

(although just airodump-ng wlan0 will work too)
and of course kismet will work here too.

Comment: I'll install this tool to my Ubuntu laptop and check it. Thanks for suggestions.